# How do I get about NoResourceException

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview

I'm trying to understand displaying a list of items in Android. From developers.android, they do explain it. However, My app crashes for some reason. I've tried putting my String array as a dummy with no fruition. This is despite the code having no errors. The stack trace says NoResourceException. The only resource is my activity file, which is in place. I'm starting to think that it may be a something beyond  the code. Maybe a dependency.

MainActivity.java

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.os.Bundle;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter adapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager;
    String[] names;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        names = new String[] {"John","Peter","James","Andrew"};
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.my_recycler_view);

        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);

        layoutManager= new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        adapter = new MyAdapter(names);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

MyAdapter.java

```
import android.view.LayoutInflater;

import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;


public class MyAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MyAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    public String[] mDataSet;

    public static class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        public TextView textView;
        public MyViewHolder(TextView itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            textView =  itemView;
        }
    }

    public MyAdapter(String[] dataSet) {
        mDataSet = dataSet;

    }



    @Override
    public MyAdapter.MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
        MyViewHolder vh = new MyViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull MyAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
        holder.textView.setText(mDataSet[position]);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mDataSet.length;
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout>
```

StackTrace

```
    android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x0
        at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1552)
        at android.content.res.Resources.getDrawable(Resources.java:926)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawableInner(Icon.java:313)
        at android.graphics.drawable.Icon.loadDrawable(Icon.java:269)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$TextViewDrawableAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1502)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2805)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.apply(RemoteViews.java:2764)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews$ViewGroupAction.apply(RemoteViews.java:1373)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.performApply(RemoteViews.java:2805)
        at android.widget.RemoteViews.reapply(RemoteViews.java:2795)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.updateNotificationViews(BaseStatusBar.java:2162)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar.updateNotification(BaseStatusBar.java:2031)
        at com.android.systemui.statusbar.BaseStatusBar$6$2.run(BaseStatusBar.java:521)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6102)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:961)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:822)
```

Updated Stacktrace

```
    java.lang.ClassCastException: androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout cannot be cast to android.widget.TextView
        at com.projects.recyclerview.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:34)
        at com.projects.recyclerview.MyAdapter.onCreateViewHolder(MyAdapter.java:12)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Adapter.createViewHolder(RecyclerView.java:6794)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.tryGetViewHolderForPositionByDeadline(RecyclerView.java:5975)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5858)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView$Recycler.getViewForPosition(RecyclerView.java:5854)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager$LayoutState.next(LinearLayoutManager.java:2230)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.layoutChunk(LinearLayoutManager.java:1557)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.fill(LinearLayoutManager.java:1517)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager.onLayoutChildren(LinearLayoutManager.java:612)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayoutStep2(RecyclerView.java:3924)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.dispatchLayout(RecyclerView.java:3641)
        at androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView.onLayout(RecyclerView.java:4194)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5600)
        at androidx.constraintlayout.widget.ConstraintLayout.onLayout(ConstraintLayout.java:1915)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5600)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5600)
        at androidx.appcompat.widget.ActionBarOverlayLayout.onLayout(ActionBarOverlayLayout.java:444)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5600)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5600)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:2001)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1844)
        at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1753)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5600)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.layoutChildren(FrameLayout.java:396)
        at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:333)
        at com.android.internal.policy.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onLayout(PhoneWindow.java:2777)
        at android.view.View.layout(View.java:17051)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:5600)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performLayout(ViewRootImpl.java:2648)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:2328)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1369)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6932)
        at android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:909)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:702)
        at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:631)
        at android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:895)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:815)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:104)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:227)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6102)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:961)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:822)
```

Comment: Have you tried cleaning the project and rebuilding it?

Comment: I don't think you have the right stack trace. `com.android.systemui.statusbar` cannot be your package. Please post the correct one.

Comment: You are right. Changed to androidx recyclerview. I got this

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using the wrong layout while trying to create the recycler view. `activity_main` is your general layout for the activity, however you're trying to use it in `onCreateViewHolder` as a list item.

You're probably looking for something called `list_item`.

`LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.list_item, parent, false);`

Be careful on the `R.layout.list_item`. You currently have `R.layout.activity_main` there. Use your correct view to inflate the list item.

Comment: I understand this now. I was inflating the wrong thing, the layout file. I take it that it should be the recyclerview created in the layout file that should be inflated. Right? Upon plugging this, its not recognized.

Comment: No, you should be inflating the layout of the list item view there, not the recycler view.

Comment: II have changed it to a list_item that I created. The only problem is the ClassCastException. Tried using the linear and relative layouts with no avail.

Answer (score 1):

```
 TextView v = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.activity_main, parent, false);
```

The root view of activity_mail isn't a TextView, it's a ConstraintLayout.  You're inflating the wrong file most likely-  its a little odd for activity_main to be inflated inside a recyclerview

Answer (score -1):

```
<androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

Instead of,

```
<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/my_recycler_view"
    android:scrollbars="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

You are using androidx in MainActivity.

Hope this solves :)

Comment: This won't fix a casting error.  Either of the two you posted is correct, depending on if he's using androidx or the older support library.

Comment: If you see that both libraries are compiled, the dependencies are applied correctly.

It only guides you to use the same library.

Comment: Casting log i missed ^^;